# Angular validate all fields on submit

Tags: angularjs, forms

I have the following directive I wrote which will check a field's validity when either a) the field's value has changed, or b) the field's element has been blurred.

First, here's an example of how the directive might be used:

```
<form name="myForm">
  <input type="text" name="favoriteColor" validate-for="myForm">
</form>
```

The reason I have to specify `myForm` is because I sometimes have nested forms. So in that case it would go like this:

```
<form name="myForm">
  <input type="text" name="favoriteColor" validate-for="myForm">
  <ng-form name="innerForm">
    <input type="text" name="favoriteNumber" validate-for="innerForm">
  </ng-form>
</form>
```

Anyway, this is what my code looks like (ES6):

```
'use strict';

class ValidateFor {
  constructor() {
    this.restrict = 'A';
    this.require = 'ngModel';

    this.link = ($scope, $element, $attrs, ngModel) => {
      var form = $scope[$attrs.validateFor];
      var field = form[$element.attr('name')];

      $scope.$watch(() => ngModel.$modelValue, () => {
        if (field.$touched) {
          this.checkForErrors(field, $element);
        }
      });

      $element.bind('blur', () => {
        this.checkForErrors(field, $element);
      });
    };
  }

  checkForErrors(field, $element) {
    if (field.$invalid) {
      $element.addClass('error');
    } else {
      $element.removeClass('error');
    }
  }
}

ValidateFor.$inject = [];

export default ValidateFor;
```

The one thing my directive does NOT do is add the `error` class to the field when the form has been submitted.

**How can I add an error class to all my fields on form submission?**

I don't care whether the solution means modifying my directive or adding code somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I approach such functionality:

I've made a directive to use it on submit button of the form. It's key function is to set `$dirty` state on all fields when user wants to submit the form - thus enabling me to show all errors that would normally be hidden. Then, if the form is valid, it runs the callback function.

```
.directive('mySubmitIfValid', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            form: '=myForm',
            submit: '&mySubmitIfValid'
        },
        link: function (scope, element) {

            element.on('click', function () {
                markFieldsAsDirty();
                submitFormIfValid();
            });

            function markFieldsAsDirty() {
                Object.keys(scope.form).filter(function (key) {
                    return key[0] !== '$';
                }).forEach(function (fieldName) {
                    scope.form[fieldName].$setDirty();
                });
            }

            function submitFormIfValid() {
                if (scope.form.$valid) {
                    scope.submit();
                }
            }

        }
    };
});
```

And then in html:

```
<form name="myForm">
  <input type="text" name="favoriteColor" ng-minlength="2">
  <input type="submit" value="Save"
   my-submit-if-valid="submitFunction()" my-form="myForm">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up simply `$broadcast`ing a `form-submitted` event when the form is submitted. Seems to work fine. Here's my code.

```
'use strict';

class ValidateFor {
  constructor() {
    this.restrict = 'A';
    this.require = 'ngModel';

    this.link = ($scope, $element, $attrs, ngModel) => {
      var form = $scope[$attrs.validateFor];
      var field = form[$element.attr('name')];

      $scope.$on('form-submitted', () => {
        this.checkForErrors(field, $element);
      });

      $scope.$watch(() => ngModel.$modelValue, () => {
        if (field.$touched) {
          this.checkForErrors(field, $element);
        }
      });

      $element.bind('blur', () => {
        this.checkForErrors(field, $element);
      });
    };
  }

  checkForErrors(field, $element) {
    if (field.$invalid) {
      $element.addClass('error');
    } else {
      $element.removeClass('error');
    }
  }
}

ValidateFor.$inject = [];

export default ValidateFor;
```